# converting a sentence to an embedding representation

Tags: word2vec, sentence-similarity

If I have a sentence, ex: “get out of here”
And I want to use word2vec Embed. to represent it .. I found three different ways to do that:

1- for each word, we compute the AVG of its embedding vector, so each word replaced by a single value.

2- as in 1, but with using the standard deviation of the embedding vector values.

3- or by adding the Embed. vector as it is. So if I use 300 length embedding vector .. for the above example, I will have in the final a vector of (300 * 4 words) 1200 length as a final vector to represent the sentence.

Which one of them is most suitable .. ? specifically, for the sentence similarity applications ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you describe option (1) makes it sound like each word becomes a single number. That wouldn't work.

The simple approach that's often used is to average all word-vectors for words in the sentence together - so with 300-dimensional word-vectors, you still wind up with a 300-dimensional sentence-average vector. Perhaps that's what you mean by your option (1).

(Sometimes, all vectors are normalized to unit-length before this operation, but sometimes not - because the non-normalized vector lengths can sometimes indicate the strength of a word's meaning. Sometimes, word-vectors are weighted by some other frequency-based indicator of their relative importance, such as TF/IDF.)

I've never seen your option (2) used and don't quite understand what you mean or how it could possibly work.

Your option (3) would be better described as "concatenating the word-vectors". It gives different-sized vectors depending on the number of words in the sentence. Slight differences in word placement, such as comparing "get out of here" and "of here get out", would result in very different vectors, that usual methods of comparing vectors (like cosine-similarity) would not detect as being 'close' at all. So it doesn't make sense, and I've not seen it used.

So, only your option (1), as properly implemented to (weighted-)average word-vectors, is a good baseline for sentence-similarities.

But, it's still fairly basic and there are many other ways to compare sentences using text-vectors. Here are just a few:

One algorithm closely related to word2vec itself is called 'Paragraph Vectors', and is often called `Doc2Vec`. It uses a very word2vec-like process to train vectors for full ranges of text (whether they're phrases, sentences, paragraphs, or documents) that work kind of like 'floating document-ID words' over the full text. It sometimes offers a benefit over just averaging word-vectors, and in some modes can produce both doc-vectors and word-vectors that are also comparable to each other.

If your interest isn't just pairwise sentence similarities, but some sort of downstream classification task, then Facebook's 'FastText' refinement of word2vec has a classification mode, where the word-vectors are trained not just to predict neighboring words, but to be good at predicting known text classes, when simply added/averaged together. (Text-vectors constructed from such classification vectors might be good at similarities too, depending on how well the training-classes capture salient contrasts between texts.)

Another way to compute pairwise similarities, using just word-vectors, is "Word Mover's Distance". Rather than averaging all the word-vectors for a text together into a single text-vector, it considers each word-vector as a sort of "pile of meaning". Compared to another sentence, it calculates the minimum routing work (distance along lots of potential word-to-word paths) to move all the "piles" from one sentence into the configuration of another sentence. It can be expensive to calculate, but usually represents sentence-contrasts better than the simple single-vector-summary that naive word-vector averaging achieves.

Comment: To find similarity between two texts, could we also find similarities between n x m words (n and m are the number of words in each text), and then average it out (like divide the sum of all scores by n*m)?

Comment: You can try anything! Whether it works, or works better than more simple approaches, needs to be tested against some real corpus/task. (As described, I suspect what you propose would give results very similar to comparing the average-of-m-words with the average-of-n-words, but involve more calculation. So it might "work" but be dominated by simpler approaches, unless further refined.)

Answer (score -2):

`
model = Word2Vec(sentences,vector_size=100, min_count=1)

def sent_vectorizer(sent, model):
sent_vec =[]
numw = 0
for w in sent:
try:
if numw == 0:
sent_vec = model[w]
else:
sent_vec = np.add(sent_vec, model[w])
numw+=1
except:
pass

```
return np.asarray(sent_vec) / numw
```

X=[]
for sentence in sentences:
X.append(sent_vectorizer(sentence, model))

print ("========================")
print (X)
`